# Fix some SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I don't want to fetch manufacturers query from this query, what would be final query without manufacturer?

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->products_query = "
        SELECT 
            p.products_model,
            pd.products_name,
            pd.products_description,
            m.manufacturers_name 
        FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p 
        INNER JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd 
            ON pd.products_id = p.products_id 
                AND pd.language_id = :languages_id 
        LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_MANUFACTURERS . " m 
            ON m.manufacturers_id = p.manufacturers_id
        WHERE p.products_id = :products_id";
} // end constructor
```

Comment: You could put in at least an _inkling_ of effort...

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->products_query = "
        SELECT 
            p.products_model,
            pd.products_name,
            pd.products_description,
        FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p 
        INNER JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd 
            ON pd.products_id = p.products_id 
                AND pd.language_id = :languages_id 
        WHERE p.products_id = :products_id";
} // end constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking to remove the manufacturer's table from the query. To do that just eliminate the LEFT JOIN and the m.manufacturers_name attribute from the query.

```
SELECT p.products_model, pd.products_name, pd.products_description
FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p 
    INNER JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd ON pd.products_id = p.products_id AND pd.language_id = :languages_id
```